# Visual Studio Ctrl K, D - HTML Tag Spacing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to Visual Studio and I'm using 2015 Community.  I don't know if this is possible, but I would like for VS to add a space between tags when I hit Ctrl K, Ctrl D so instead of this:
[image]

I get this:
[image]

Is it possible to configure this in VS?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Options/Text editor/HTML (Web forms)/Formatting/Tag specific options.

There is a "Line breaks" option in the section "Per tag formatting". Set it according to your preference for each item in the "Default settings" folder.

Comment: Thank you!.  I went under ASP.NET Controls and I don't see DropDownList or CheckBoxList as one of the options.  I guess those line breaks are not configurable?  I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can use the 'New tag...' option to add a tag to the list.

Comment: That did it!  Great!  Thank you @Sándor Mátyás Márton!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sándor Mátyás Márton's advice, I went to Options > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting > Tag Specifics Options (button).

Then, I clicked on ASP.NET Controls > New Tag > and added the controls I wanted to modify.

In the Line Breaks Drop down, I chose "2 Before opening, within, and 2 after closing" to get the effect I was looking for.